# Bluetooth Stopped Working on Ubuntu 20.04.4 - Extension section signature mismatch

Tags: drivers, usb, bluetooth

**Summary:**
I use a Bluetooth headset which connects via a Bluetooth USB dongle to my desktop and it no longer works.

**Specific Error:**
hci0: RTL: extension section signature mismatch

**Supporting Information:**

Initially I was having an error saying `rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin not found` but I solved that and the subsequent `rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_config.bin not found` by following the instructions found [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/rtl_bt).

I've tried the suggestions for the "mismatch" error from a few different troubleshooting posts and tutorials and they haven't helped. I'm fairly inexperienced with using and maintaining bluetooth on a  linux machine but I hope the information below proves I'm at least thorough.

`sudo dmesg |grep -i bluetooth`

```
[    3.759294] usb 1-10: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[    5.713666] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.713798] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    5.713800] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.713805] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.713807] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.713811] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.782910] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0a hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0a lmp_subver=8761
[    5.785903] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[    5.785907] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin
[    5.786694] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_config.bin
[    5.786862] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: extension section signature mismatch
[   13.211210] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   13.211213] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   13.211217] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

`rfkill list all`

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`sudo systemctl status bluetooth`

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-07-26 09:55:14 BST; 29min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 950 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38371)
     Memory: 1.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─950 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jul 26 09:55:14 TheOncomingStorm systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Jul 26 09:55:14 TheOncomingStorm bluetoothd[950]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
Jul 26 09:55:14 TheOncomingStorm systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Jul 26 09:55:14 TheOncomingStorm bluetoothd[950]: Starting SDP server
Jul 26 09:55:14 TheOncomingStorm bluetoothd[950]: Bluetooth management interface 1.21 initialized
```

`sudo bluetoothctl`

```
[bluetooth]# show
No default controller available
```

I've also tried restarting the bluetooth service and restarting the computer.

`lsusb`

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 25a7:fa23  
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 045e:07a5 Microsoft Corp. Wireless Receiver 1461C
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05a3:9331 ARC International Camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:8771 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I looked [here](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:0bda-8771) to see if the drivers needed updating for the dongle.

`lsmod`

```
Module                  Size  Used by
ccm                    20480  3
bnep                   28672  2
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
intel_rapl_common      36864  1 intel_rapl_msr
nvidia_uvm           1171456  0
edac_mce_amd           36864  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek   147456  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    98304  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     73728  1
kvm                   991232  0
nvidia_drm             65536  9
snd_hda_intel          53248  9
nvidia_modeset       1200128  14 nvidia_drm
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
snd_usb_audio         344064  2
snd_hda_codec         155648  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
aesni_intel           376832  2
snd_hda_core          106496  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_usbmidi_lib        45056  1 snd_usb_audio
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  2 snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec
cryptd                 24576  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
rtl8192ee             167936  0
snd_pcm               135168  6 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
btcoexist             241664  1 rtl8192ee
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
uvcvideo              106496  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
rtl_pci                40960  1 rtl8192ee
snd_rawmidi            45056  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_usbmidi_lib
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
rtlwifi               114688  3 rtl_pci,btcoexist,rtl8192ee
btusb                  61440  0
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
rapl                   20480  0
nvidia              35352576  712 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
joydev                 32768  0
input_leds             16384  0
gigabyte_wmi           20480  0
videobuf2_v4l2         32768  1 uvcvideo
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
snd_seq                73728  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
btbcm                  24576  1 btusb
mac80211             1228800  3 rtl_pci,rtlwifi,rtl8192ee
videobuf2_common       77824  4 videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_memops
btintel                40960  1 btusb
wmi_bmof               16384  0
drm_kms_helper        303104  1 nvidia_drm
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
k10temp                16384  0
bluetooth             679936  12 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb
snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
videodev              249856  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
cec                    61440  1 drm_kms_helper
mc                     61440  5 videodev,snd_usb_audio,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
rc_core                61440  1 cec
cfg80211              954368  2 rtlwifi,mac80211
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
snd                   102400  34 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
sysfillrect            20480  1 drm_kms_helper
ecc                    36864  1 ecdh_generic
soundcore              16384  1 snd
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ccp                    98304  0
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
mac_hid                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  6
ipmi_devintf           20480  0
ipmi_msghandler       122880  1 ipmi_devintf
msr                    16384  0
parport_pc             53248  0
ppdev                  24576  0
drm                   602112  13 drm_kms_helper,nvidia,nvidia_drm
lp                     28672  0
parport                69632  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               53248  1 ip_tables
autofs4                49152  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 65536  0
hid                   147456  2 usbhid,hid_generic
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
nvme                   49152  2
r8169                  86016  0
ahci                   45056  0
gpio_amdpt             20480  0
xhci_pci               20480  0
i2c_piix4              28672  0
nvme_core             126976  3 nvme
realtek                32768  1
xhci_pci_renesas       20480  1 xhci_pci
libahci                40960  1 ahci
wmi                    32768  2 gigabyte_wmi,wmi_bmof
gpio_generic           20480  1 gpio_amdpt
```

`modinfo btusb`

```
filename:       /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko
license:        GPL
version:        0.8
description:    Generic Bluetooth USB driver ver 0.8
author:         Marcel Holtmann <marcel@holtmann.org>
firmware:       mediatek/mt7668pr2h.bin
firmware:       mediatek/mt7663pr2h.bin
srcversion:     4ADD4C15BB3F20C025D802E
alias:          usb:v8087p0A5Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0930p*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v413Cp*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v0A5Cp*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v04CAp*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v0489p*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v0BB4p*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v105Bp*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v19FFp0239d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0C10p0000d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDBp1002d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v044Ep3002d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v044Ep3001d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04BFp030Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v057Cp3800d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v05ACp8281d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v05ACp821Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v05ACp821Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v05ACp821Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v05ACp8218d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v05ACp8215d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v05ACp8213d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A5Cp21E1d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E8Dp763Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v05ACp*d*dc*dsc*dp*icFFisc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v*p*d*dc*dsc*dp*icE0isc01ip01in*
alias:          usb:v*p*d*dcE0dsc01dp04ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v*p*d*dcE0dsc01dp01ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          of:N*T*Cusb4ca,301aC*
alias:          of:N*T*Cusb4ca,301a
alias:          of:N*T*Cusbcf3,e300C*
alias:          of:N*T*Cusbcf3,e300
alias:          of:N*T*Cusb1286,204eC*
alias:          of:N*T*Cusb1286,204e
depends:        btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bluetooth
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           btusb
vermagic:       5.15.0-41-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        6D:67:B7:35:44:6D:C3:54:18:19:C3:8C:69:9C:C6:A9:66:9F:AA:19
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      46:DB:14:54:CC:BE:82:B6:6F:97:C6:25:C7:4D:77:A0:BF:8D:0A:98:
        59:01:90:F4:CE:20:7A:97:81:24:03:59:36:9D:94:51:3C:E4:B2:9D:
        E1:6A:DB:53:83:3A:42:0C:CC:AF:C9:63:A6:93:6E:92:AD:B1:40:14:
        BE:E4:C6:78:6F:8C:E1:A5:A6:93:DD:32:99:70:A0:A3:A2:A6:7C:AB:
        84:B2:95:38:16:35:B0:73:B9:73:ED:E8:94:B7:4E:8A:5A:28:80:3F:
        80:B1:7E:62:FA:9E:F4:43:EA:76:B7:D2:81:00:49:80:E8:1D:36:CD:
        8E:0D:70:67:23:9E:31:EA:6F:B4:74:30:D3:71:67:18:57:0C:65:E4:
        F0:FF:FB:86:35:C0:56:99:0D:47:A6:23:5C:FA:43:15:FE:FC:C5:20:
        11:4B:EA:C5:26:2E:E4:FC:CB:3A:47:A6:DF:A7:A8:C8:9F:55:C0:42:
        34:71:1D:36:DE:9A:A7:D8:75:AB:E0:B5:C2:49:74:E7:EE:9E:FC:20:
        AE:6D:1E:AA:34:C6:56:B3:0F:03:E3:D5:53:56:4B:19:5A:7C:68:3D:
        56:D2:A6:63:38:C1:93:14:CE:5F:8C:16:F0:9F:AC:72:68:49:B2:C0:
        A7:3A:BF:99:77:4C:DF:66:65:7B:34:B0:4C:D3:B2:09:48:5F:8C:1B:
        C7:E4:27:39:29:9F:66:7F:4E:26:46:F9:A6:D4:E7:B7:7C:F2:CC:10:
        D3:37:8B:71:8B:7E:57:AD:CB:A6:E8:0E:F5:A0:26:7D:3C:55:D5:38:
        51:DE:FC:C7:CE:97:20:55:23:34:2A:3C:4F:1C:05:E1:59:A6:C8:3C:
        3D:BC:30:95:8C:86:FB:82:47:58:DE:10:B5:D4:EA:40:4F:03:E1:7B:
        3F:1B:7B:1D:48:54:4B:98:FD:4C:C2:6D:CB:EC:C1:AD:8B:E2:8B:48:
        4D:BE:B4:5C:BE:52:7D:74:83:9D:A6:8D:BF:B1:16:AC:5D:86:F1:68:
        6F:01:68:4D:BB:32:22:D3:E7:10:BE:D3:9B:29:6F:6C:9E:96:AA:0B:
        CB:5D:DD:C6:D5:8E:E0:2C:68:F2:84:F9:83:4D:98:9E:8D:F5:3B:65:
        6A:EE:EB:44:91:03:28:86:35:22:8B:EB:48:6D:EA:D9:E8:34:E4:1B:
        5E:2A:FE:9C:1A:63:B6:C2:FF:07:FA:07:EF:7C:3A:0F:F0:B3:5C:6E:
        54:47:B8:9F:9F:E7:87:E7:21:91:4B:EA:2F:DB:4D:5B:10:25:A6:3A:
        91:BB:A0:AA:8E:2F:4E:76:DF:64:AB:2F:81:06:5C:69:71:9F:81:63:
        34:D1:1B:B1:3F:F3:78:7F:17:86:C1:75
parm:           disable_scofix:Disable fixup of wrong SCO buffer size (bool)
parm:           force_scofix:Force fixup of wrong SCO buffers size (bool)
parm:           enable_autosuspend:Enable USB autosuspend by default (bool)
parm:           reset:Send HCI reset command on initialization (bool)
```

`ls /usr/lib/firmware/rtl_bt`

```
rtl8192ee_fw.bin               rtl8723d_config.bin   rtl8761bu_fw.bin     rtl8822b_config.bin   rtl8852au_config.bin
rtl8192eu_fw.bin               rtl8723d_fw.bin       rtl8812ae_fw.bin     rtl8822b_fw.bin       rtl8852au_fw.bin
rtl8723a_fw.bin                rtl8761a_fw.bin       rtl8821a_config.bin  rtl8822cs_config.bin  rtl8852bu_config.bin
rtl8723b_fw.bin                rtl8761b_config.bin   rtl8821a_fw.bin      rtl8822cs_fw.bin      rtl8852bu_fw.bin
rtl8723bs_config-OBDA8723.bin  rtl8761b_fw.bin       rtl8821c_config.bin  rtl8822cu_config.bin  rtl8852cu_config.bin
rtl8723bs_fw.bin               rtl8761bu_config.bin  rtl8821c_fw.bin      rtl8822cu_fw.bin      rtl8852cu_fw.bin
```

`lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:05.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
00:08.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B]
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 61)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron/Crucial Technology Device 5403 (rev 03)
02:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset USB 3.1 XHCI Controller (rev 01)
02:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset SATA Controller (rev 01)
02:00.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Bridge (rev 01)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01)
03:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01)
03:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
06:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117 [GeForce GTX 1650] (rev a1)
07:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
08:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function
09:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP
09:00.1 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Cryptographic Coprocessor PSPCPP
09:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
09:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
0a:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)
0b:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)
```

Comment: Did you rename rtl_bt/rtl8761b_fw.bin to rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin?

Comment: Hi @Jeremy31 I downloaded rtl_bt/rtl8761_bu_fw.bin and rtl_bt/rtl8761_bu_config.bin as they were different files to rtl_bt/rtl8761_b_fw.bin and rtl_bt/rtl8761_b_config.bin at  the repo I downloaded from.